# Why no "insertAssociation" function?

Tags: sapui5

I am writing a custom control and have an association declared like this:

```
details: {type: "sap.m.IconTabFilter", multiple: true, singularName: "detail"}
```

In the debugger I can see that there is an `addAssociation` function available, but there is no `insertAssociation` function (I am extending from `sap.m.ResponsivePopover` if that makes a difference).

My use-case is that I have an `sap.m.IconTabBar` that is internal to my control which I populate internally. But I also need to allow consumers to pass in their own custom tabs.

I want consumers to be able to instantiate my control using XML view types for example, so I am trying to expose a "details" association so they can seamlessly add the custom tab without having to create their own IconTabBar.

Is my understanding of associations incorrect?

Comment: This sounds more like an aggregation (strong relation) than an association  (weak relation) to me. You can define your `details` as aggregation. The framework will then create `insertDetail(oContent, iIndex)` for you as described [here](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#insertAggregation).

Comment: @TimGerlach The reason I (think) I want to use associations here is that the IconTabFilter objects the consumer would be passing in are immediately added to my internal IconTabBar aggregation. Meaning, they would be re-parented as soon as I added them to the IconTabBar. That would create an inconsistent API if they were aggregations from the consumer's point of view as the "getDetails" function would return nothing due to the re-parenting.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring it multiple says to the framework to store the association as an array. You are getting a method called `getDetails()` for this association. And also an `addDetail` and a `removeDetail()` method. Not sure if I understood your question because if you have a `addDetail` to add content to the association why do you want the insert?
J.

Comment: The insertAssociation function would presumably allow you insert at a certain position in the array like you can with insertAggregation. I suppose I could make my own insertAssociation function by modifying the internal associations array directly, but it would be nice if the framework supported that or if I was missing something fundamental about the usage of associations.

Comment: Reading from here: https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#.extend the insert method is not available